# Foreach inside shortcode not working as planned

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, terms, php

I have a loop inside a shortcode to display the list of posts for each category (schedule-day) in a custom post type (schedule).

The first category lists the posts in said category just fine, but the second category lists posts from both the first and second category.

Anyone experienced this issue before?

```
$terms = get_terms('schedule-day', 'hide_empty=1&orderby=name&order=ASC');
if(!empty($terms)) :

    $verytop = '<div class="tabs"><ul>';

      foreach($terms as $term) :

          $term_name = $term->slug;
          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'schedule', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'schedule-day' => $term_name);
          $query = new WP_Query( $args );

          $top .= '<li><a href="#' . $term->slug . '">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
          $close = '</ul>';

          if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();   
            $next = '<div id="'.$term->slug.'" class="itinerary">';       
              $middle .= '<div class="schedule-item '.$term->slug.'" title="'.$term->slug.'"><div class="schedule_content"><h3>'. get_the_title() . '</h3>' . get_the_content() . '</div></div>';   
            $nexter = '</div>'; 
          endwhile; endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        $fish .= $next.$middle.$nexter;

          endforeach;

          $verybottom = '</div>';
          return $verytop.$top.$close.$fish.$verybottom;
      endif;
```

Comment: Each post has just one category?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the categories to break up the 'schedule' into days

Comment: possibly related to the use of an invalid character (hyphen) in the taxonomy name? From [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy): *Name should only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character, and not be more than 32 characters long*

Comment: Thanks Milo, I change the taxonomy name but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could it be just due to the concatenation of some of the vars? $middle for example is never reset anywhere.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head Welcher! I reset $middle just before the if query and it works fine now! Thank you!